# bootstrap import data dir command not working

Tags: blockchain-import

Hi I am trying to import the raw blockchain into my linux computers Persistent folder, however the command to tell it to do that will not work

if I type

```
./monero-blockchain-import --data-dir /home/amnesia/Persistant
```

however, it still imports it to my /home/ folder

am I using the wrong command?

How can i specify where the blockchain is imported to??

Comment: Looks it's probably a bug, but after the db is imported, you can just move the directory, and it'll work fine (assuming the new place supports mmap).

Comment: Is this binary from monero 0.11.0.0 ? Can you include look at the log to see what it says on the line with  "database path" ?